# No artifact files found Circle CI React Native iOS

Tags: react-native, automation, circleci, fastlane, circleci-2.0

I am new to Circle Ci and somehow I accomplish to automate the ios app to test-flight but didn't get the Artifact of .ipa in the circle-ci dashboard.

In the pipeline, I get Uploading Artifacts successful but with No artifact files found

```
Uploading /Users/distiller/demo-react-native/ios/XXXX.ipa to ios/XXXX.ipa  
 No artifact files found at /Users/distiller/demo-react-native/ios/XXXX.ipa
```

In my circle-ci config.yaml file this is the path I have given

```
  - store_artifacts:
      path: ios/XXXX.ipa
```

Maybe I am giving the wrong path. If anyone knows the exact path or what the issue is it will be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance